# Read data stored as text and use in IF statement

Tags: mysql

I have a column that stores dates as `text`, I need to select all the entries with date less than the date of today.

If I use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytab
WHERE expire < CURRENT_DATE( ) 
ORDER BY expire DESC
```

It doesn't select the correct entries but only the ones with `da_expire` empty.

How can I fix it?

Comment: what is the format of your date?

Comment: Can you switch the schema to use the correct column type? This will be brutally slow since it must evaluate *every* row for this query.

Comment: No I can't switch, by the way are just few houndred of rows. The format is `yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place, why are you storing it as string?

You need to convert it to date using MySQL's builtin function so you can be able to compare it with today's date.

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(expire, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i') < CURDATE()
```

This will be a little slower since it will not use any index if you have one defined on the column.

- [MySQL Docs: STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

Use  STR_TO_DATE(expire, '%m/%d/%Y') instead of expire in the query. I have assumed you are storing the date in month day year format. You will need to adjust the format as per the string format. However, for performance reasons convert the type of expire during load/insert process .